# HOG+SVM for side face detection

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection

I'm quite new to computer vision area and need to know whether there is a python model developed for side face detection using HOG and SVM other than dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() which detects frontal faces.

Searched in the web but couldnt find any resource.